# Eclipse formatter: New line after annotations/public?

Tags: eclipse, formatting

IntelliJ has some such facilities and options. For example, I want it to format like:

```
@Override public
void foo()
{  ...  }
```

Better yet would be the ability to indent the annotations and visibility like so

```
    @Override public
void foo()
{ ... }
```

but I don't want to be greedy.

Do such formatting options exist in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit --> New Lines --> Annotation:

Unclick Insert new line after annotations on methods

Don't think you can do your second option.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't have a setting for moving public/private/protected.

Answer (score 3):

In case you still have Annotation formatting problems in Eclipse 2018 (Oxygen.3a, 4.7.3a) try this:

In Preferences go to: **Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit --> New Lines --> Annotations:**

[image: eclipse oxygen Annotation formatting]

You have to select Annotations and then **set "line wrapping policy" to a "Wrap ..." setting**. Without this setting any complex set of Annotations was formatted to very long lines in Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

**Go to settings-> Editor-> Code Style -> Java**

Choose your code formatter and choose tab **Wrapping and Braces** (Try to find tab Wrapping if using different Intellij Version).

Look for option Class Annotation and Method Annotation and select option **"Wrap Always"**

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Open the preferences dialog. Go to "Java" -> "Code Style" -> "Formatter".

Check the many options :-)

Comment: I wasn't able to find such an option, but I'd hate to have just overlooked it.